# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, database-connection

I am getting this error don't know the reason 
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied` 
and here is the website on which i am tryiing to upload my file `example.com`.

Comment: You will have to change/set the MYSQL database userid and password in your app, to match what you or your hosting company set them to

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 60):

This happens because selinux avoids db connections from the httpd server to the remote db server. To solve it you need to access your server through ssh or just open a console if you have pretencial access and do the following:

You must check in the SELinux if port 80 is managed in. You can check it by typing `# semanage port -l | grep http_port_t` for a list and check:

`http_port_t                    tcp      443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000`

If you need to add the required port, just type:

`# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 80`

Type the command to ckeck once again:

`# semanage port -l | grep http_port_t`

.

`http_port_t                    tcp      80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000`

Then you should notify SELinux you want to allow network connections from the httpd server to the db remote server, setting the boolean variables that set it:

1. Down the httpd service `# service httpd stop`
2. `# setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1`
3. `# setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`
4. Up the httpd service `# service httpd start`

Now your httpd service should be capable to get data from the db server.

These changes wont remain after a reboot. To make them permanent, instead do the following:

1. Down the httpd service `# service httpd stop`
2. `# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`
3. `# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`
4. Up the httpd service `# service httpd start`

The difference is the "-P" flag.

I hope that can be useful for the gang that searches solve errors like this.

Comment: Worked for me, but after a reboot, these settings will go away. You will need to permanently make them by using the -P switch like # setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Comment: This worked like a charm on CentOS 7, Wordpress. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on Centos 9 Stream

Answer (score 26):

Go in .env file and change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to DB_HOST=localhost

Comment: This seems like the socket / UNIX issue, localhost works on socket while 127.0.0.1 works on tcp

Answer (score -1):

May I am late to answer this question but what worked for me are the commands.
I ran into same issue and then I ran the following commands.

Provide permissions:

`chmod -R 777 .` (though not recommended)

Run setup upgrade command

```
php bin/magento setup:ugrade
```

and finally compile command

```
php bin magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score -5):

Maybe you need to shut down your selinux
just like this

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: This is not recommended.

Comment: There is no selinux on FreeBSD, still I get this error. :)